# Android - Rotation menu with one part out of the screen

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, rotation

I want develope [this rotation](http://leteckaposta.cz/606851209) in my App . I have implemented the "down" menu ("můj dealer", "moje Volvo", "kontakty") and I need implement the "upper" rotating menu.

How can I do it? Do you have tips? Hope you understand me.

Images (please, watch the video above in the link):

[image]
[image]

**Menu_item_test.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/menuItemImg"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/tab_1_1" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Activity_main.xml:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/rotationMenu" >
</FrameLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageViewShadow"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
    android:contentDescription="shadow"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/half_round_back" />

<cz.mixedapps.volvista.RotationMenu
    android:id="@+id/rotationMenu"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="265dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >
</cz.mixedapps.volvista.RotationMenu>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have put together a custom view which replicates the behaviour, you still have to style it like in you example, but it works with an arbitrary number of child views and currently looks like this:

[image]

**EDIT:** I added the ability to show and hide the upper rotating menu with two methods, `showRotationMenu()` and `hideRotationMenu()`:

[image]

Of course there is a lot you can do to improve this view. I just wrote this in 15 minutes and therefor it is a little rough around the edges. But it should be more than enough to put you on the right track. Both the looks of the buttons and of the views which rotate is completely customisable.

### 1) Source

RotationMenu.java:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.database.DataSetObserver;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.animation.*;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

/**
 * Created by Xaver Kapeller on 26/03/14.
 */
public class RotationMenu extends LinearLayout {

    private final DataSetObserver dataSetObserver = new DataSetObserver() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged() {
            super.onChanged();
            reloadAdapter();
        }
    };

    private RotationMenuAdapter adapter;
    private FrameLayout flViewContainer;
    private LinearLayout llMenu;
    private View currentView;
    private View previousView;

    private int animationPivotX;
    private int animationPivotY;

    private int selectedPosition = 0;

    public RotationMenu(Context context) {
        super(context);

        setupMenu();
    }

    public RotationMenu(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        setupMenu();
    }

    public RotationMenu(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);

        setupMenu();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);

        this.animationPivotX = w / 2;
        this.animationPivotY = h;
    }

    private void setupMenu() {
        this.setOrientation(VERTICAL);
        this.flViewContainer = new FrameLayout(getContext());
        this.addView(this.flViewContainer, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, dpToPixel(150)));

        this.llMenu = new LinearLayout(getContext());
        this.llMenu.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        this.addView(this.llMenu, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    }

    private int dpToPixel(int dp) {
        float scale = getDisplayDensityFactor();
        return (int) (dp * scale + 0.5f);
    }

    private float getDisplayDensityFactor() {
        Resources res = getResources();
        if (res != null) {
            DisplayMetrics metrics = res.getDisplayMetrics();
            if(metrics != null) {
                return metrics.density;
            }
        }
        return 1.0f;
    }

    public RotationMenuAdapter getAdapter() {
        return this.adapter;
    }

    public void setAdapter(RotationMenuAdapter adapter) {
        if (adapter != null) {
            if (this.adapter != null) {
                this.adapter.unregisterDataSetObserver(this.dataSetObserver);
            }
            adapter.registerDataSetObserver(this.dataSetObserver);
            this.adapter = adapter;
            reloadAdapter();
        }
    }

    public boolean isRotationMenuVisible() {
        return this.flViewContainer.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE;
    }

    public void showRotationMenu() {
            if(this.flViewContainer.getVisibility() != View.VISIBLE) {
                this.flViewContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                AnimationSet set = new AnimationSet(false);

                TranslateAnimation translateAnimation = new TranslateAnimation(Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 1, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0);
                translateAnimation.setDuration(1000);
                set.addAnimation(translateAnimation);

                AlphaAnimation alphaAnimation = new AlphaAnimation(0, 1);
                alphaAnimation.setDuration(1000);
                set.addAnimation(alphaAnimation);

                this.flViewContainer.startAnimation(set);
            }
    }

    public void hideRotationMenu() {
        if(this.flViewContainer.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
            AnimationSet set = new AnimationSet(false);

            TranslateAnimation translateAnimation = new TranslateAnimation(Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 1);
            translateAnimation.setDuration(1000);
            set.addAnimation(translateAnimation);

            AlphaAnimation alphaAnimation = new AlphaAnimation(1, 0);
            alphaAnimation.setDuration(1000);
            set.addAnimation(alphaAnimation);

            set.setAnimationListener(new ViewAnimationEndListener(this.flViewContainer) {
                @Override
                protected void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation, View view) {
                    view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            });

            this.flViewContainer.startAnimation(set);
        }
    }

    private void reloadAdapter() {
        Context context = getContext();
        if (this.adapter != null && context != null) {
            int viewCount = this.adapter.getCount();
            int oldViewCount = this.llMenu.getChildCount();
            for (int i = 0; i < Math.max(oldViewCount, viewCount); i++) {
                if (i < viewCount) {
                    LayoutParams layoutParams = new LayoutParams(0, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1);
                    View menuItem;
                    if (i < this.llMenu.getChildCount()) {
                        menuItem = this.adapter.getMenuItemView(i, this.llMenu.getChildAt(i), this.llMenu);
                        if(menuItem.getParent() == null) {
                            this.llMenu.removeViewAt(i);
                            this.llMenu.addView(menuItem, i, layoutParams);
                        }
                    } else {
                        menuItem = this.adapter.getMenuItemView(i, null, this.llMenu);
                        this.llMenu.addView(menuItem, layoutParams);
                    }
                    menuItem.setOnClickListener(new MenuItemClickListener(i));
                } else {
                    this.llMenu.removeViewAt(i);
                }
            }

            this.flViewContainer.removeAllViews();
            this.previousView = this.currentView;
            if (this.selectedPosition >= viewCount) {
                this.selectedPosition = viewCount - 1;
            }
            this.currentView = this.adapter.getView(this.selectedPosition, this.previousView, this);
            addViewWithAnimation(this.currentView, false);
        }
    }

    public void switchToItem(int position, boolean animate) {
        if (this.adapter != null) {
            int viewCount = this.adapter.getCount();
            position = valueInRange(position, 0, viewCount - 1);

            if (position != this.selectedPosition) {
                View oldView = this.currentView;
                this.currentView = this.adapter.getView(position, this.previousView, this);
                this.previousView = oldView;

                addViewWithAnimation(this.currentView, animate, position < this.selectedPosition);
                removeViewWithAnimation(this.previousView, animate, position < this.selectedPosition);

                this.selectedPosition = position;
            }
        }
    }

    private int valueInRange(int value, int min, int max) {
        if (value > max) {
            value = max;
        } else if (value < min) {
            value = min;
        }
        return value;
    }

    private void addViewWithAnimation(View view, boolean animate, boolean leftToRight) {
        if (view != null) {
            if(view.getParent() == null) {
                this.flViewContainer.addView(view, new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            }
            if (animate) {

                int start = leftToRight ? -90 : 90;

                Animation rotateIn = new RotateAnimation(start, 0, this.animationPivotX, this.animationPivotY);
                rotateIn.setDuration(1000);

                view.startAnimation(rotateIn);
            }
        }
    }

    private void addViewWithAnimation(View view, boolean animate) {
        addViewWithAnimation(view, animate, true);
    }

    private void removeViewWithAnimation(View view, boolean animate, boolean leftToRight) {
        if (view != null) {
            if (animate) {

                int target = leftToRight ? 90 : -90;

                Animation rotateOut = new RotateAnimation(0, target, this.animationPivotX, this.animationPivotY);
                rotateOut.setDuration(1000);
                rotateOut.setAnimationListener(new ViewAnimationEndListener(view) {
                    @Override
                    protected void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation, View view) {
                        flViewContainer.removeView(view);
                    }
                });
                view.startAnimation(rotateOut);
            } else {
                this.flViewContainer.removeView(view);
            }
        }
    }

    private void removeViewWithAnimation(View view, boolean animate) {
        removeViewWithAnimation(view, animate, true);
    }

    private abstract class ViewAnimationEndListener implements Animation.AnimationListener {

        private final View view;

        private ViewAnimationEndListener(View view) {
            this.view = view;
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            onAnimationEnd(animation, this.view);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

        }

        protected abstract void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation, View view);
    }

    private class MenuItemClickListener implements OnClickListener {

        private final int position;

        MenuItemClickListener(int position) {
            this.position = position;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(adapter != null && adapter.isMenuItemEnabled(this.position) && isRotationMenuVisible()) {
                switchToItem(this.position, true);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

RotationMenuAdapter.java:

```
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;

/**
 * Created by Xaver Kapeller on 26/03/14.
 */
public abstract class RotationMenuAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    public abstract View getMenuItemView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent);
    public abstract long getMenuItemId(int position);
    public abstract boolean isMenuItemEnabled(int position);
}
```

### 2) Usage:

The custom view is making use of adapters and view recycling, so you use it the same way you would use a `ListView`. Because of the view recycling it is not very memory intensive and actually pretty fast. The logic for the creating of the menu items at the bottom is also in the adapter and it too uses view recycling. So be sure that you implement `getMenuItemView()` with the same care you would use to implement `getView()`. First you have to write an adapter:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import at.test.app.R;
import at.test.app.RotationMenu.RotationMenuAdapter;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Xaver Kapeller on 26/03/14.
 */
public class TestAdapter extends RotationMenuAdapter {

    private static final long TEST_VIEW_ID = 0;
    private static final long DEFAULT_VIEW_ID = TEST_VIEW_ID;

    private static final long TEST_MENU_ID = 0;
    private static final long DEFAULT_MENU_ID = TEST_MENU_ID;

    private final LayoutInflater inflater;
    private final List<TestViewModel> viewModels;

    public TestAdapter(Context context, List<TestViewModel> viewModels) {
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.viewModels = viewModels;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return this.viewModels.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return this.viewModels.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {

        Object viewModel = getItem(position);

        if(viewModel instanceof TestViewModel) {
            return TEST_VIEW_ID;
        }

        return DEFAULT_VIEW_ID;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if(getItemId(position) == TEST_VIEW_ID) {
            TestViewModel viewModel = (TestViewModel) getItem(position);

            TestRow row;
            if(convertView == null) {
                convertView = this.inflater.inflate(TestRow.LAYOUT, parent, false);
                row = new TestRow(convertView);
                convertView.setTag(row);
            }

            row = (TestRow) convertView.getTag();
            row.bind(viewModel);
        }

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public View getMenuItemView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if(getMenuItemId(position) == TEST_MENU_ID) {
            TestViewModel viewModel = (TestViewModel)getItem(position);

            MenuRow row;
            if(convertView == null) {
                convertView = this.inflater.inflate(MenuRow.LAYOUT, parent, false);
                row = new MenuRow(convertView);
                convertView.setTag(row);
            }

            row = (MenuRow)convertView.getTag();
            row.bind(viewModel);
        }

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public long getMenuItemId(int position) {
        Object item = getItem(position);

        if(item instanceof TestViewModel) {
            return TEST_MENU_ID;
        }

        return DEFAULT_MENU_ID;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isMenuItemEnabled(int position) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Nothing special, except the extra methods for the creating of the menu items. In `isMenuItemEnabled()` you can add logic to enable/disable menu items if you need to.

And then you apply your adapter to the view:

```
List<TestViewModel> viewModels = new ArrayList<TestViewModel>();

TestViewModel menuItemOne = new TestViewModel();
menuItemOne.setMenuItemIconResId(R.drawable.icon);
viewModels.add(menuItemOne);

TestViewModel menuItemTwo = new TestViewModel();
menuItemTwo.setMenuItemIconResId(R.drawable.icon);
viewModels.add(menuItemTwo);

TestAdapter adapter = new TestAdapter(getActivity(), viewModels);
this.rotationMenu.setAdapter(adapter);
```

**EDIT:**

Try this layout with `wrap_content` instead `match_parent`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/menuItemImg"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/tab_1_1" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I'm also no so sure about your `layout_width`, are you sure you need `match_parent` there? I don't think so.

Comment: I have one more question:) How can I hide "upper" rotation menu? For example with some animation the "upper" menu will scroll down behind the "down" menu an disapeare or scroll up and it´s back visible.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are asking. You want to hide the upper menu completely? I can add that to the custom view if you want. Should there be an animation in which the upper menu would slide behind the lower menu?

Comment: Yes, I want programmatically hide/show the upper menu completely and there should be an animation (exactly as you write). I will be gratefull to you if you edit your code. And I hope it will help some other people in future.

Comment: This shouldn't be that difficult to add. I will edit my code, but please give me some time to do it. I've got a lot to do right now but I think I will find the time in the next few hours. I will comment here when I am finished.

Comment: I edited my answer, there are now two methods to show and hide the upper rotating menu, `showRotationMenu()` and `hideRotationMenu()`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have one question to you. I implemented your menu at the bottom of activity and when user click at the button in TestRow I want change the rest of activity above the menu. For example there will be a list or some textviews or map. The best solution will be if I could define this list/textviews/map in some layouts and dynamically "put" this layout above the menu. Is it possible? Do you understand me? How would you implement this?

Comment: That would be a classic use case of fragments. You create different fragments with the layouts and functionality you need and exchange them with a `FragmentTransaction`.

Comment: Everything works ok, but I have one problem. When I use hideRotationMenu() then the buttons in down menu expand all the entire Rotation menu. Look at the screenshots: http://goo.gl/8a0oO6 and http://goo.gl/Zp5lne . Do you know, where can be problem? How you define the main layout and menu layout?

Comment: I see. I can' test right now, but my first intention would be to try to change the line `view.setVisibility(View.GONE);` in the `AnimationListener` of the `AnimationSet` in the method `hideRotationMenu()` to `view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);`. That would most certainly solve your problem. But I suspect it would also cause problems because anything behind the now invisible rotation menu wouldn't be clickable. Please edit your menu item layout xml into your question, I think the error is there.

Comment: Yes, now it´s ok. I have last question to you :) In main layout I have RotationMenu and FrameLayout (set layout_above="@+id/rotationMenu") and when I run hideRotationMenu(), then the Fragment should expand to the buttons in down menu (screen: http://goo.gl/D2mH8S). Is it possible? How can I do this?

Comment: This is exactly what I meant in my last comment. if you change that line to `view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);` then the rotationMenu doesn't really disappear. It is invisible, but still part of the layout and influencing other parts like the fragment. As I said, you shouldn't change that line to `view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)` but instead post your menu item xmls. if you watch the second gif I posted above you can see that my menu items do not get stretched when I hide the rotation menu. That they get stretched in your implementation just means that something is wrong with them.

Comment: I added Menu_item_test.xml.  What is different between my and your? (If I remove android:scaleType="fitXY", there is still same problem). I also add activity_main.xml.

Comment: It has nothing to do with the `scaleType`, but as I suspected you have `match_parent` as `layout_height`, that means that it would stretch if space is available. Change it to `wrap_content`.

Comment: I changed `mach_parent` to `wrap_content` but no succes ([image1](http://imageshack.com/a/img856/9973/fomx.png) , [image2](http://imageshack.com/a/img21/2628/8u4k.png) ). Isn´t problem that I specified 'layout_height' for RotationMenu in acitivity_main.xml?

Comment: You specified a fixed height for the rotation menu? Don't do that! And according to your images it did work, the menu items don't strech anymore.

Comment: The rotation menu needs `wrap_content` as height.

Comment: I edited layouts and now it´s OK. In menu_items_test.xml a set `layout_width="match_parent"` to stretch menu items horizontally. Thanks for your help

Comment: Did you try RotationMenu in Android 2.3.3? I try it now and after rotation I get [this exception](http://imageshack.com/a/img69/95/hm79.png). Show/hide rotation menu works good but afrer rotation app throws exception. Do you know where can be problem?

Comment: From the looks of the exception it is probably unrelated to the rotation menu. It should work on 2.3.3 the same way out does on 4.0+.

Comment: [Solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5569267/nullpointerexception-that-doesnt-point-to-any-line-in-my-code) for the exception...