# Android java.lang.NullPointerException at animation end

Tags: android

Im facing and exception while removing the view at animation end. Its happening only when the application is brought to foreground at the same time when the animation is played. Below is the code snippet. Any help would be appreciated.

```
public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                                new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        try{
                                            setActivePlayer(nextPlayer, time);
                                            String source = discardAnimationCard.getCardSource();
                                            openCard.updateCardSource(source);
                                            if(gameTable.indexOfChild(discardAnimationCard) >= 0){
                                                gameTable.removeView(discardAnimationCard);
                                            }
                                            String discardAckMessage = "DiscA#";
                                            String round = "1";
                                            if( gameId.indexOf("-") >= 0 ){
                                                round = gameId.split("-")[1];
                                            }
                                            discardAckMessage += gameCode+"@"+round+":"+source;
                                            gameDataReader.gameHandler.sendMessage(discardAckMessage);
                                        }catch(Exception e){

                                        }

                                    }
                                });
```

Below is the stack trace

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2954)
            at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14509)
            at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13403)
            at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13445)
            at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14223)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3118)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2955)
            at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14509)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:472)
            at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13403)
            at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13445)
            at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14223)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3118)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2955)
            at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13398)
            at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13445)
            at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14223)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3118)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2955)
            at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14509)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:472)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:2452)
            at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13403)
            at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13445)
            at android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.buildDisplayList(HardwareRenderer.java:1570)
            at android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.draw(HardwareRenderer.java:1449)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2431)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2301)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1931)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1047)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5896)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5105)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:792)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:608)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Please click [edit] and add the _stacktrace_ as output by LogCat. We can not debug that which we can not see. Voting to close due to lack of context.

Comment: The above stack trace is taken from LogCat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android will make an exception when you change the view hierarchy in animationEnd.
Check this link it will solve your problem 
[NullPointerException that doesn't point to any line in my code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5569267/nullpointerexception-that-doesnt-point-to-any-line-in-my-code)

Comment: In the above code i have used Handler post. But still the exception occurs

Comment: That solutions is not working for me. Anything else. Im still facing the issue... ??