# Android View is still getting OnClick() even by set its visibility to GONE

Tags: android, visibility, onclicklistener

I know there are few questions regard this issue but all of them are using animation. I have no animation at all in my activity. I have a TextView that by default is visible and is set to Gone based on a Feature-Flag that I get in my Splash screen.

This is my xml file:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/profile_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/profile_bg"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="?android:actionBarSize">

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/payments_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="6dp"
            android:background="@drawable/profile_payment_bg"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_profile_payment"
            android:drawablePadding="8dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:text="Payment"
            android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

...

    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Although I'm setting Clickable and OnClickListener functionality to false and null respectively, OnClick() functionality is called even when my Payment button is not visible :(

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);

        this.mPayments = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.payments_btn);

        // Check if payment functionality available for the Passenger
        final PassengerFeatureResponse cachedFeature = FeatureResponse.fromJsonString(PreferenceUtils.getFeatureResponse(this));
        if (cachedFeature == null || !cachedFeature.isMade())
        {
            this.mPayments.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            this.mPayments.setClickable(false);
            this.mPayments.setOnClickListener(null);
        }
    }
```

I even tried to set visibility to Gone from xml file and set it to visible from code however the functionality was same :(

It's probably because I have defined `onClick` functionality from xml file and my problem would be fixed if I set click listener from code, however, I'm looking for fix the issue in this way.

Any suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: If you set the visibility as GONE, the view is completely removed from the layout. It doesn't even take any space. I'd first confirm if that actually happens ? (I don't think its possible to click something that doesnt even show up on the screen)

Comment: `mPayments.setVisibility(View.GONE);` is more than enough. And it will definately work.

Comment: Thanks guys but as you can see in following link, others have same problem as well, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4728908/android-view-with-view-gone-still-receives-ontouch-and-onclick. I am still able to click the item even when the view is gone :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this on `FrameLayout` like this

```
  this.frameMain= (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.profile_layout);
       if (cachedFeature == null || !cachedFeature.isMade())
        {
            this.mPayments.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            this.mPayments.setClickable(false);
            this.mPayments.setOnClickListener(null);
            this.frameMain.invalidate();
        }
```

Comment: Nice guess Nilesh, thanks but unfortunately didn't work :( based on what I know invalidate functionality tries to redraw the view rather than changing attributes of the view.

Answer (score 0):

After these line:

```
        this.mPayments.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        this.mPayments.setClickable(false);
```

Add these lines:

```
        this.mPayments.setFocusable(false);
        this.mPayments.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
```

** **EDIT** **

Ignore the focusable snippet and try to disable the view like this:

```
         this.mPayments.setEnabled(false);
```

You can check if a view can receive click events to make sure everything is rite:

```
         this.mPayments.isClickable(); // Indicates whether this view reacts to click events or not.
```

If the above shows false, then it shouldn't react to click events.

Comment: Thanks Sharp, didn't work unfortunately :( although my problem is about clic-ability rather that focusability.

Comment: Thanks man for spending your time but didn't work unfortunately :(

Comment: have you checked if the `view.isClickable()` returns true ?

Answer (score 0):

When you use `onClick` pattern, you must define a `View` as parameter on the method implemented in your class.

Maybe you can use a **switch** with the ID of the view, then check if `payments_btn` is still visible and fire your action only if is visible.