# fillAfter and fillEnabled not working in Android view animation XML

Tags: android, animation

I'm curious as to this behavior ... I'm currently setting the two values in the anim XML:

```
    android:fillEnabled="true"
    android:fillAfter="true"
```

However, the transformation does not apply after the animation is done ... it always resets. When I set it programmatically via code it does seem to work:

```
    animation.setFillEnabled(true);
    animation.setFillAfter(true);
```

So I'm just curious how this should work, as I'd rather set it on the XML. Thanks!

Comment: Your question had the answer I was looking for

Comment: as xml sequential loading animation and starting cause this problem with one animation with fillafter true works perfect

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It also works if you don't have the set tag and are just doing translate or something like so.

```
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"       
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"       
    android:fromXDelta="0"
    android:toXDelta="0"
    android:fromYDelta="1000"
    android:toYDelta="-300" 
    android:startOffset="100"
    android:duration="1000"
    android:fillAfter="true" />
```

Answer (score 69):

I had the same problem, this worked for me:

```
<set
    android:fillEnabled="true"
    android:fillAfter="true"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <translate
        android:fromYDelta="0"
        android:toYDelta="-20%p"
        android:duration="7000" />

</set>
```

Put the attributes *fillEnabled* and *fillAfter* in the Set tag.

Comment: I was having this issue with a RotateAnimation and your comment helped solve the issue. Cheers.

Comment: thanks a lot, did the trick for me :) link you to another post :)

Comment: Doesnt work for my animations with min and target set 14 and 19 respectively on a Nexus 4 with 4.4.4. Animation always reverts back to original ImageView.

Comment: Hi @RichieHH I am facing the same problem. Did you get any solution to your problem ?

Comment: as xml sequential loading animation and starting cause this problem with one animation with fillafter true works perfect

Answer (score 8):

In general, use the **fillAfter** and **fillEnabled** on the root element

so either

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillAfter="true"
    android:fillEnabled="true"
    android:fromXDelta="0%"
    android:toXDelta="-100%"
    android:duration="500" />
```

OR

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillAfter="true"
    android:fillEnabled="true">
    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="0%"
        android:toXDelta="-100%"
        android:duration="500" />
</set>
```

Comment: Actually I was not setting these values in root but in inner set so I was facing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

putting the fillEnabled and fillAfter attributes in the set tag helped solved the issue.