# Trying to Move a Button to Another Point on the Screen

Tags: android, android-animation

I am trying to move 3 buttons relative to their starting points:

The code for starting the animation is:

```
protected void showMoreBtns() {
    Button btn1 = (Button)this.findViewById( R.id.more1btn );
    Button btn2 = (Button)this.findViewById( R.id.more2btn );
    Button btn3 = (Button)this.findViewById( R.id.more3btn );

    Animation showMore = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation( this, R.anim.optionsinup1 );
    btn1.startAnimation( showMore );

    showMore = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation( this, R.anim.optionsinup2 );
    btn2.startAnimation( showMore );

    showMore = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation( this, R.anim.optioninup3 );
    btn3.startAnimation( showMore );
}
```

And the animation is defined as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="0"
        android:fromYDelta="0"
        android:toXDelta="-60"
        android:toYDelta="-30" />
</set>
```

All three animations follow the same format, with only the `android:toDelta`'s being modified.

The issues is the animation runs, yet the buttons return to their original position at the end of the animation.  I would like them to stay at the end point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

showMore.setFillAfter(true);
This will be placed in your java code.
I hope it will be work.If you want to use the button after complete animation you will placed onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) in that place the button using your layout.

Answer (score 1):

You need two sets of buttons, and after the animation is played you have to make one set disappear, probably using `View.setVisibility(View.GONE)` on its parent or on each Button.

Comment: Is there a simpler way to move elements to different points on the screen.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will help you but i was struck with the same problem i was  able to do this using these methods,
setTranslationX(float)
setTranslationY(float)

you can use it Like this

```
Button button = (button) findViewById(your id); 
button.setTranslationX(a float value);
```

here's the android documentation that provide more information
[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:translationX](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android%3atranslationX)

also note that the minimum level of android SDK required is 11

Comment: It looks good for current versions of Android, but at the time I asked this question, I was working with Android 2.x, and most likely SDK level 7 or 8.