# "Unexpected text found in layout file" error in anim xml file in Android Studio?

Tags: android, animation

I am trying to create an anim file. But the lines in set tag has dark bacgrounden and when I move my mouse over that dark backgrounded place it says following message.

Unexpected text found in layout file: "android:interpolator="@android:anim/bounce_interpolator""

[image: Here is the screenshot of the case]

Comment: XML attributes go inside XML elements (the `< >` stuff). Your attribute is outside of any element.

Comment: There many examples using this sort of usage of attributes. For example  [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6510300/fillafter-and-fillenabled-not-working-in-android-view-animation-xml/31808403       see Josh Cole's post.

Comment: All the ones that I see on that page are inside the XML elements. For example, [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8698156/115145) has the `android:interpolator` attribute inside the `<translate>` element. Similarly, in [Josh Cole's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6519233/115145), all of the attributes are inside of the elements. In your case, your attribute is not.

Comment: Thank you. I got it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try moving your XML attribute into the XML element:

```xml
<set
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:interpolator="@android:anim/bounce_interpolator">
```

Also, please note that this is an animation resource and [goes in a `res/anim/` directory](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource?hl=en), not `res/layout/`.

Comment: Yes, it is in res/anim directory but the error message  says ".... layout file..."        by the way, problem solved. Thank you                                            On the other hand, I need to ask, how can I go tothe next line while adding comment in here. Because ENTER  key posts immediatelly, I tried alt_enter, crtl_enter. but no chance. Help section says two space at the end of line but nothing. :)

Comment: @ucanbizon: OK. That might be a bug in the IDE's error message. I could not tell from your screenshot what directory it was in.