# Rotate animation keep return to its default state

Tags: android, android-animation

I have rotation animation that  starts vertically and ends horizontally (90 degrees).
 I need to make the animation stay horizontally until some button is pressed, but it just keeps going back to its vertical state
**Click listeners:**

```
holder.options.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                holder.options.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context,R.anim.rotate_right));
                setMenuOptionsButton();
            }}
```

**The animation**

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<rotate
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:toDegrees="90"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:duration = "500"
    android:fillAfter="true"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    />
```

**I saw** [some solutions here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10203577/android-rotate-animation-get-back-to-its-real-state-after-finishing-the-animati) **and it didn't help me**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context,R.anim.rotate_right);
anim.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        holder.options.setRotation(90);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

    }
});

holder.options.startAnimation(anim);
```