# Android view animation doesn't stay

Tags: android, animation

I have searched internet, but haven't found answer to my problem.
I want to animate a view to slide up. But how can I keep it there? It always resets and goes back to original position.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3345084/how-can-i-animate-a-view-in-android-and-have-it-stay-in-the-new-position-size ...That's the first result you get if you google 'Android animation view stay'

Answer (score 2):

`public void setFillAfter (boolean fillAfter)`

Added in API level 1
If fillAfter is true, the transformation that this animation performed will persist when it is finished. Defaults to false if not set. Note that this applies to individual animations and when using an AnimationSet to chain animations.

see more here: [Android Animation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html#setFillAfter%28boolean%29)